# Insert em massa com Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework-6

Tenho um projeto onde o usuário seleciona um arquivo txt ou csv, e o sistema lê linha a linha passando os campos para uma entidade. Da primeira vez, executava `SaveChanges()` do contexto do banco a cada linha do arquivo. Mas isso estava demorando muito e depois de 20mil linhas dava erro de timeout.

Após algumas pesquisas resolvi preencher a entidade e adicionar ao contexto e depois do arquivo todo ser lido, salvar o contexto todo de uma vez. mas agora estou recebendo o erro "A transação associada à conexão atual foi concluída, mas não foi descartada. A transação deve ser descartada antes do uso da conexão para executar as instruções SQL."

Tentei usar o package BulkInsert, mas também não consegui.

Alguém sabe uma solução? Segue meu código.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    ContextoBanco context = null;
    try
    {
        using (context = new ContextoBanco())
        {
            context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

            int count = 0;
            if (extension.ToLower() == ".csv")
            {

                //string filename = Path.GetFileName(UploadedFile.PostedFile.InputStream);
                StreamReader csvreader = new StreamReader(file.InputStream, Encoding.Default);
                var header = csvreader.ReadLine();
                string[] cols = header.Split(';');

                while (!csvreader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = csvreader.ReadLine();
                    var values = line.Split(';');

                     Cadastrar(cols, values, file.FileName, context);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (extension.ToLower() == ".txt")
            {
                //string filename = Path.GetFileName(UploadedFile.PostedFile.InputStream);
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file.InputStream);
                sr.ReadLine();

                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = sr.ReadLine();
                    var values = line.Split(';');

                    Cadastrar(values, file.FileName, context, count);
                }
            }

            context.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.InnerException.ToString();
    }

    scope.Complete();
}

private void Cadastrar(string[] cols, string[] values, string filename, ContextoBanco context, int count)
{

    Entidade evento = new Entidade();
    evento.nome = values[0];
    evento.data = values[1];
    evento.tipo = values[2];
    evento.valor = values[3];

    RepositorioBase<Entidade> rep = new RepositorioBase<Entidade>();
    rep.AddToContext(context, evento);
}

public ContextoBanco AddToContext(ContextoBanco context, TEntidade entity)
{
    context.Set<TEntidade>().Add(entity);

    return context;
}
```